# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion

No one leaves a comment on it, just close(2), anything bad about this question ?

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82836/what-words-should-i-use-in-replacement-of-lazy

Comment: You din't specify what kind of word you wanted. So it is too open ended. Also, you could easily have looked in a thesaurus for 'tired' to find all sorts of things (including all the suggested answers).

Comment: @Mitch ah, I never know about `thesaurus`, thanks, I was about to ask how should I cope with similar questions without asking them, now I know a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be improved by doing research to try to answer your own question, and including the results in your question. That is basic site etiquette. Please see the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) and the linked document on asking good questions.